# How to use Light Theme in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, themes

I updated the visual studio, and now I have the same theme of the program as on the phone, it is dark on the phone, and I want the program to be light, please help,I tried Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Light,but it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Changing properties dynamically**

First step is to swap StaticResource for DynamicResource every view properties that will be impacted by your theme update.
Doing so, when you will set the DynamicBackgroundColor from black to white for example, it will be automatically propagated to all the properties referencing this key.

Let's have a look at our App.xaml:

```
<Color x:Key="DarkSurface">#121212</Color>  
<Color x:Key="LightSurface">#00FF0266</Color>

...

<Style ApplyToDerivedTypes="True" TargetType="ContentPage">  
<Setter Property="Padding">
    <Setter.Value>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
            <On Platform="iOS">0, 20, 0, 0</On>
            <On Platform="Android">0, 0, 0, 0</On>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource DynamicBackgroundColor}" />
</Style>

<Style ApplyToDerivedTypes="True" TargetType="NavigationPage">  
    <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource 
                                                   DynamicNavigationBarColor}" />
    <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="{DynamicResource DynamicBarTextColor}" />
</Style>
```

We can see that DynamicResource works also with styles...

The catch with DynamicResource values is that you won't define it in your styles like classic StaticResource.
For example DynamicBackgroundColor is not defined anywhere in the xaml, you can regard them as references waiting to be assigned.

You assign them dynamically in your code like this (we'll see the SetDynamicResource implementation right after that):

```
// Dark Mode
SetDynamicResource(DynamicBackgroundColor, "DarkSurface");

// Ligh Mode
SetDynamicResource(DynamicBackgroundColor, "LightSurface");
```

**Switching between Light and Dark mode**

In my Silly App! bottom bar I have a TabButton with a toggle theme icon, clicking on it will call either SetDarkMode() or SetLightMode():

```
namespace SillyCompany.Mobile.Practices.Presentation.Views{
   public static class ResourcesHelper{
        public const string DynamicPrimaryTextColor = nameof(DynamicPrimaryTextColor);
        public const string DynamicSecondaryTextColor = nameof(DynamicSecondaryTextColor);

        public const string DynamicNavigationBarColor = nameof(DynamicNavigationBarColor);
        public const string DynamicBackgroundColor = nameof(DynamicBackgroundColor);
        public const string DynamicBarTextColor = nameof(DynamicBarTextColor);

        public const string DynamicTopShadow = nameof(DynamicTopShadow);
        public const string DynamicBottomShadow = nameof(DynamicBottomShadow);

        public const string DynamicHasShadow = nameof(DynamicHasShadow);

        public const string Elevation4dpColor = nameof(Elevation4dpColor);

        ...

        public static void SetDynamicResource(string targetResourceName, string sourceResourceName)
    {
        if (!Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue(sourceResourceName, out var value))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"key {sourceResourceName} not found in the resource dictionary");
        }

          Application.Current.Resources[targetResourceName] = value;
      }

      public static void SetDynamicResource<T>(string targetResourceName, T value)
      {
          Application.Current.Resources[targetResourceName] = value;
      }

      public static void SetDarkMode()
      {
           MaterialFrame.ChangeGlobalTheme(MaterialFrame.Theme.Dark);
           SetDynamicResource(DynamicNavigationBarColor, "DarkElevation2dp");
           SetDynamicResource(DynamicBarTextColor, "TextPrimaryDarkColor");

           SetDynamicResource(DynamicTopShadow, ShadowType.None);
           SetDynamicResource(DynamicBottomShadow, ShadowType.None);
           SetDynamicResource(DynamicHasShadow, false);

           SetDynamicResource(DynamicPrimaryTextColor, "TextPrimaryDarkColor");
           SetDynamicResource(DynamicSecondaryTextColor, "TextSecondaryDarkColor");

           SetDynamicResource(DynamicBackgroundColor, "DarkSurface");

           SetDynamicResource(Elevation4dpColor, "DarkElevation4dp");
       }

       public static void SetLightMode(){
           MaterialFrame.ChangeGlobalTheme(MaterialFrame.Theme.Light);
           SetDynamicResource(DynamicNavigationBarColor, "Accent");
           SetDynamicResource(DynamicBarTextColor, "TextPrimaryDarkColor");

           SetDynamicResource(DynamicTopShadow, ShadowType.Top);
           SetDynamicResource(DynamicBottomShadow, ShadowType.Bottom);
           SetDynamicResource(DynamicHasShadow, true);

           SetDynamicResource(DynamicPrimaryTextColor, "TextPrimaryLightColor");
           SetDynamicResource(DynamicSecondaryTextColor, "TextSecondaryLightColor");

           SetDynamicResource(DynamicBackgroundColor, "LightSurface");

           SetDynamicResource(Elevation4dpColor, "OnSurfaceColor");
        }
   }
}
```

You can see that I am not only changing colors, but also disabling shadows in dark mode, since dark modes are flat by essence.

Example: **SillyBottomTabsPage.cs**

```
<tb:Toolbar x:Name="Toolbar"  
        Title="Silly App!"
        BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource DynamicNavigationBarColor}"
        ForegroundColor="White"
        HasShadow="{DynamicResource DynamicHasShadow}"
        Subtitle="The Official sample app for the Sharpnado's components" />

...

<tabs:TabHostView   x:Name="TabHost"  
                Grid.Row="2"
                BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Elevation4dpColor}"
                ShadowType="{DynamicResource DynamicTopShadow}"
                TabType="Fixed"
                SelectedIndex="{Binding Source={x:Reference Switcher}, 
Path=SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">

<tabs:TabButton x:Name="TabButton"
                IsVisible="True"
                ButtonBackgroundColor="{StaticResource Accent}"
                ButtonCircleSize="60"
                ButtonPadding="15"
                IconImageSource="theme_96.png"
                Scale="1.3"
                TranslationY="-10"
                Clicked="TabButtonOnClicked" />

...
```

**Making the transition**
And now let's see the code for our transition:

**SillyBottomTabsPage.xaml.cs**

```
private void TabButtonOnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e){
    TaskMonitor.Create(AnimateTabButton);
}

private void ApplyTheme(){

   if (_currentTheme == Theme.Light) {
        ResourcesHelper.SetLightMode();
        return;
   }

   ResourcesHelper.SetDarkMode();
}

private async Task AnimateTabButton(){

    double sourceScale = TabButton.Scale;
    Color sourceColor = TabButton.ButtonBackgroundColor;
    Color targetColor = _currentTheme == Theme.Light
    ? ResourcesHelper.GetResourceColor("DarkSurface")
    : Color.White;

    // Bounce then remove icon from button,
    await TabButton.ScaleTo(3);
    await TabButton.ScaleTo(sourceScale);
    TabButton.IconImageSource = null;

    // Ballon inflation
    var bigScaleTask = TabButton.ScaleTo(30, length: 500);
    // Change color to target dark/light mode
    var colorChangeTask = TabButton.ColorTo(
    sourceColor,
    targetColor,
    callback: c => TabButton.ButtonBackgroundColor = c,
    length: 500);

    // run animation at the same time
    await Task.WhenAll(bigScaleTask, colorChangeTask);

    _currentTheme = _currentTheme == Theme.Light ? Theme.Dark : Theme.Light;
    ApplyTheme();

    // reverse inflation and color animation to accent color
    var reverseBigScaleTask = TabButton.ScaleTo(sourceScale, length: 500);
    var reverseColorChangeTask = TabButton.ColorTo(
    targetColor,
    sourceColor,
    c => TabButton.ButtonBackgroundColor = c,
    length: 500);

    await Task.WhenAll(reverseBigScaleTask, reverseColorChangeTask);

    // icon is back
    TabButton.IconImageSource = "theme_96.png";
}
```

Comment: I want to turn off Dark Theme.and use only Light,how to do it?

Comment: how do you get _currentTheme?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `AppThemeBinding` to set the light theme or the dark theme.

Download the source file from the link below and make some changes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-systemthemesdemo/

When you set dark mode on the phone and want the program to be light, you could change the xaml like below:

**Change:** ContentPage BackgroundColor

```
 BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightPageBackgroundColor}, Dark={StaticResource DarkPageBackgroundColor}}">
```

**To:**

```
 BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource DarkPageBackgroundColor}, Dark={StaticResource LightPageBackgroundColor}}">
```

**Change:** Grid BackgroundColor

```
 <Grid BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightPrimaryColor}, Dark={StaticResource DarkPrimaryColor}}">
```

**To:**

```
 <Grid BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource DarkPrimaryColor}, Dark={StaticResource LightPrimaryColor}}">
```